# Python: Strange x axis limits using matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

(Python newbie here) As a learning exercise I am trying to solve and plot the solution to a very simple ODE: dy/dt = y with y(0) = 1. I believe my code to solve the ODE is correct, but the x-axis limits of the plot are very strange. I made 50 equally spaced x-values ranging from 0 to 5, but it looks as if `plt.plot()` is plotting only the first two points, resulting in the graph looking like a line rather than the curve y = e^x. I tried playing around with the 'scalex' and 'scaley' arguments of `plt.plot()`, and I also tried `plt.xlim = (0,5)`, and variations thereof, but to no avail. My code is below (I'm using Python 3.7.6):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(t,y):
    return(y)

t0 = np.linspace(0,5,50)
y0 = np.array([1])

#solve_ivp(fun, t_span, y0, args = None)
out = solve_ivp(f, t0, y0)

t_vals = out.t
y_vals = out.y[0,:]

plt.plot(t_vals,y_vals)
```

Here's the plot I'm getting:

[image]

I did try setting `y = np.exp(t0)` and then plotting t0 vs y0, which works perfectly (i.e. with the x values ranging from 0 to 5). So I'm not sure why my original code is not giving me the same type of graph. Perhaps my attempt to subset the variable `out` is somehow incorrect? ...Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the [documentation for solve_ivp](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html), you can see that `t_span` should be a 2-tuple of floats, and you can specify the step with `max_step`

So you can have:

```
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(t,y):
    return(y)

out = solve_ivp(f, (0, 5), [1], max_step=0.1)

t_vals = out.t
y_vals = out.y[0,:]

plt.plot(t_vals,y_vals)
```

Which gives you the expected graph:
[image]

Comment: Thank you! I didn't read the documentation carefully enough :)